# Django ImageField Template Injection

Tags: django

I have checked multiple sources and I can't find any pattern to how the template tags are referenced for ImageFields. Can someone please explain to me every single little part to the template tag call. For instance, {{emp.emp_image.url}} - the first spot before the period has no reference anywhere I look. Not in views, models. No references ever. The second argument is the Field in the model and then urls is a Django argument. What is the first part?

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Name - {{emp.name}}</h1>
    <img src="{{emp.emp_image.url}}" alt="Smiley face" width="250" height="250">
    <br />
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go Back!!!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share a code of `views.py`?

Comment: are you okay with `emp.name`? and what do you call `template tags` here?

Answer (score 0):

**{{emp.emp_image.url}}** :

[1] emp before the period is the name of the variable you sent to the HTML template or commonly known as **Context Dictionary** parameter.

[2] emp_image is the name of the attribute in your model

[3] url is the parameter that your image which gives django the location of the image

Comment: Is this what you wanted to know ??